# Stopping a column calculation with a variable start date, and restarting after 9 rows in Excel

Tags: if-statement, variables, excel-formula, line-breaks, sumproduct

I have a column of calculations in Excel that I want to run for 81 rows, then not calculate for 9 rows, then continue calculating for 81 rows etc.
The problem I have is that the start of the column calculations varies dependant on the start date, which could be any day.

I am stopping the calculations using SUMPRODUCT function to count the NonBlank cells
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(C10:C90)<>0))=81,"",??????????,C$8/2)
but I am struggling to work out how to restart it again and continue after 9 rows as shown below.
Any help much apprciated ;0)

| Row | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 01/05/23 | 25.00 |
| 90 | 02/05/23 | 25.00 |
| 91 | 03/05/23 |  |
| 92 | 04/05/23 |  |
| 93 | 05/05/23 |  |
| 94 | 06/05/23 |  |
| 95 | 07/05/23 |  |
| 96 | 08/05/23 |  |
| 97 | 09/05/23 |  |
| 98 | 10/05/23 |  |
| 99 | 11/05/23 |  |
| 100 | 12/05/23 | 25.00 |
| 101 | 13/05/23 | 25.00 |

Comment: would you maybe prefer to have the dates in sequence skipping the dates you don't want to show, like this: `=LET(start,DATE(2023,2,11),
repeat,3,
days,81,
skip,9,
TOCOL(start+SEQUENCE(repeat,days,0)+SEQUENCE(repeat,,0,skip)))` you can then change the `repeat` value to how many times you want to repeat the sequence of 81 dates with the gap of 9 days in between them.

Comment: You can always use the above to match against: `=LET(start,DATE(2023,2,11), repeat,3, days,81, skip,9,IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A1:A100,TOCOL(start+SEQUENCE(repeat,days,0)+SEQUENCE(repeat,,0,skip)))),C8/2,""))`

Comment: Hi P.b. Thanks for the reply, I understand the logic of your reply, but I'm guessing it's VBA? & I'm sorry to say I know very little about that & I do not know how to integrate it into my spreadsheet. My apologies. R

Comment: It's not VBA, it's a formula, but you need Office365 for that to work.

Comment: Ah, I have Office 2016 ;0(

Comment: Then try this in `B1` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,DATE(2023,2,11)-1+ROW($1:$100)+INT((ROW($1:$100)-1)/81)*9,0)),$C$8/2,"")` provided that feb-11th 2023 is the start date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older Excel here's two options:

**Option 1**
*Create a list of dates that skip 9 after every 81st row*

This can be accomplished by the following formula in your start cell of the date range:

```
=DATE(2023,2,11)
 +ROW()-1
 +(INT((ROW()-1)/81)*9)
```

If this is used in the *first row* of column A (or any different column) you can drag this down and after every 81st row it'll skip 9 numbers and continue from there.

If you plan on not using the first row, the `-1` needs to be amended (for both cases).

In this case you don't need to calculate the value in column B based on the dates it should skip, because we just accomplished that.

It sums the start date + the current row number minus 1 and adds the integer of the current row number minus 1 divided by 81. The result of the integer (0 for the first 81 rows, 1 for the next 81, etc..) is multiplied by 9.

**Option 2**
*Check against a list of dates that skip 9 after every 81st row*

Note, this requires an array formula and option 1 is probably more advisable.

If we want a full list of dates in column A and calculate the value for 81 rows, then skip 9 and repeat, we can use the following formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,
                   DATE(2023,2,11)
                   +ROW($1:$100)-1                
                   +INT((ROW($1:$100)-1)/81)*9,
                   0)),
    $C$8/2,
    "")
```

This is an array formula and requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.

In this case we need to hardcore the number of rows (dates) you need to use. If you want to expand the number of dates you need to change `100` in `ROW($1:$100)` (both places where it's used in the formula) don't forget the `$` in front to lock the value when dragging the formula.

This formula checks if the date value in column A exists in the date array created inside the array formula. If it does, it calculates `$C$5/2` else it shows a blank value.

If we use Office 365 the date sequence can be created using:

```
=LET(start,  DATE(2023,2,11),
     repeat, 3,
     days,   81, 
     skip,   9,
TOCOL(start+SEQUENCE(repeat,days,0)+SEQUENCE(repeat,,0,skip)))
```

This spills in one go.

Or the date checker using:

```
=LET(start,  DATE(2023,2,11),
     repeat, 3,
     days,   81, 
     skip,   9,
IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A1:A100,
                   TOCOL(start+SEQUENCE(repeat,days,0)+SEQUENCE(repeat,,0,skip)))),
   C8/2,
   ""))
```

Comment: Hi P.b Thats great & I really appreciate you taking time to explain this process as clearly as you have. This has helped me understand your suggestion so thank you. I'll give this a go & get back to you. Many thanks ;0)

Comment: Hi P.b  The array function works brilliantly, just as asked, I have never ventured into arrays before so thank you for enlightening me! Is it ok for me to ask further questions relating to this, here, or do I need to edit my original question?

Comment: Feel free to ask. If it's an addition to this, it's probably worth a new question. If it's asking about explaining more into dept, ask it here. If my post answered your question, you can mark the post as a good answer by clicking the `V` next to my post.

Comment: ok ta, is it possible to reverse the sequence using an array? i.e. skip 9 rows then do the calcs for the next 81 & so on?

Comment: Do you mean: `=DATE(2023,2,11)+ROW()-1 +(INT((ROW()+80)/81)*9)` ? I don't see the purpose of it though, since changing the start date would suffice.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it was just a thought. Many thanks for all your help.